# group extention problem

Tags: group-theory

The group U(1) can be extended by Z to give the real line R.
In this process we go from a compact topologically non-trivial space to topologically trivial non-compact one.

I wonder now if there exist analogous construction for U(n). So, I would like to extend U(n) by a discrete group to get a non-compact group with trivial topology.

Is that possible?

Comment: In what way are you doing this extension? It does not actually seem to be a group extension.

Comment: You really need to describe a bit more how to extend $U(1)$ by $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: I mean that U(1)=R/Z and wonder if there exist G and T (with T discrete) such that U(n)=G/T

Comment: Ok, so there is a big difference between $U(1)$ and $U(n)$, $U(1)$ is not simply connected while $U(n)$ are simply connected for $n\ge 2$.

Comment: To John. U(n) are not simply connected. SU(n) are. Still SU(n) have non-trivial topology. Can I unfold this by adding a discreet subgroup

Comment: Yes, you are right. To I guess you can take the universal cover of $U(n)$, just like what you did for $U(1)$, but this universal still has higher nontrivial homotopy groups.